# joining two tables and getting minimum value out of it in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two different tables in sql both contaning name and marks. I want to make new table having colums names and minimum marks out of two tables for each name.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to do a `UNION` of the two tables and then query out the minimum mark for each name:

```
SELECT t.name, MIN(t.mark) AS min_mark
FROM
(
    SELECT name, mark FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name, mark FROM table2
) t
GROUP BY by t.name
```

Comment: I think you miss group by name

Comment: @krishnpatel Thanks for that edit, yes I forgot `GROUP BY`

Comment: @krishnpatel can you please tell me why we haven.t use join instead of union ?

Comment: @tim-biegeleisen ?

Comment: You want to be able to apply the `MIN()` function to a combination of the records from each table.  This implies using `UNION`.

Comment: you can also do it by join but you need a complicated **CASE** condition.  this is easy way you can do it. if you want to use by join only then give my your select query I will implement it.

Comment: Answering questions as poor as this one does a disservice to the community.